# Is there a way to get route in Laravel only if it's allowed in "web.php" for current/custom user?

Tags: laravel, routes, permissions, laravel-9

I have the web.php with routes which are protected with "can:whatever" middlewares according to desired access structure (using Gates or Policies, doesnt matter).

What I want to do now is to send particular routes from controller to view/vue only if user has access to this route according to web.php (and to display or not controls according to routes existance).

I'm aware that I can check each permissions with Gate::allows and so on, but my thout is that I already have permissions structure set up in web.php and I dont want to repeat this logic by checking each permission in controllers again.

So, is there a way to check **if particular route allowed for user according to web.php file (by route name)** instead of checking each permission?

Comment: nope, since there is nothing about a route in general that says anything about permissions ... that is only a middleware doing that for you which isn't the route itself ... if you wanted to filter all routes from a route list that have a certain middleware or something you could potentially do that